# Why does the threads run even when the python script has finished its execution

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am curious why the threads started in a python script are running even when the last statement of the script is executed (which means, the script has completed (I believe)).

I have shared below the code I am talking about. Any insights on this would be helpful:

======================================================================================

```
import time
import threading

start=time.perf_counter()

def do_something():
    print("Waiting for a sec...")
    time.sleep(60)
    print("Waiting is over!!!")

mid1=time.perf_counter()

t1=threading.Thread(target=do_something)
t2=threading.Thread(target=do_something)

mid2=time.perf_counter()

t1.start()

mid3=time.perf_counter()

t2.start()

finish=time.perf_counter()

print(start,mid1,mid2,mid3,finish)
```

Comment: I'm not an expert on threading but don't you need to tell the thread to stop by calling t1.end() or something similar?

Comment: well, you can use join() to hold the code for the thread to complete. But the context of my question is a bit different. I hope my other comment sheds light on my context

Comment: Hello @akashtk, Were you able to solve this issue? How to terminate all the threads once main script terminates?

Answer (score 0):

What output do you see? This is what I see:

> Waiting for a sec...

> Waiting for a sec...

> 95783.4201273 95783.4201278 95783.4201527 95783.4217046 95783.4219945

Then it's quiet for a minute, and displays:

> Waiting is over!!!

> Waiting is over!!!

and *then* the script ends.

That's all as expected. As part of shutting down, the interpreter waits for all running threads to complete (unless they were created with `daemon=True`, which you should probably avoid until you know exactly what you're doing). You told your threads to sleep for 60 seconds before finishing, and that's what they did.

Comment: Hi Tim,

That's exactly what I see too. Here is the thing, I read that there is no child/parent relationship between threads ie, even if thread A which is starting thread B is killed, thread B will still run. The only exception for this is the case when the main thread itself is killed. I reckon this was mentioned with respect to Java. But then, I though, if the same were to apply for python, once the main program (the main thread, that initiates the child) are done with its work, shouldn't the child threads be killed as per the above logic.Hence this question.

Comment: Python never kills a thread on its own. Period. Context, and who started what, are irrelevant. If you're determined to exit a program while a non-daemon thread is still running, you need to call `os._exit()` (notice the leading underscore), which skips _all_ normal exit processing. Part of which is, as already explained, waiting for non-daemon threads to terminate. Although, even in that case, Python isn't killing threads - the operating system does.